# Select li element with arrow keys (up and down) using (jQuery) from li tag in ajax response

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In below code i am getting values using foreach loop in li  tag those li contain name and id so what i expect is when it display li item one by one when arrow down or arrow up  key press particular value get selected and show value 'a' or 'b' in text box with that select value id show in input type hidden box again select next value show that  id in hidden and value appear in text box .here is my code.

```
 output:
    <start output here>
        <li  class="optn_list"  data-id='  1 ' data-uname=' a '>value a</li>
        <li  class="optn_list"  data-id='  2 ' data-uname=' b '>value b</li>
        <li  class="optn_list"  data-id=' 3' data-uname='c '>value c</li>

    <end of output>

        <input type="text" name="usr_name" id="search_user_name" value=""    />
        <input type="hidden"  id="hidden_id" value=""    />


            function get_user_name() {
                            var name = 'xyz';
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "<?= base_url('controller/method') ?>",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: {
                                    name: name,
                                },
                                success: function (response) {

                                    $(".user_res").html('<div id="getTagField"><ul>' + response + '</ul></div>');

$('input').keydown(function(e)
{
 if ( key !== 40 && key !== 38 ) return;
else{

//here how to write condition to select one by one list item using arrow up or down key with focus on selected item

}
)};


                                }

                            });

                        }
```

Comment: It's a bit complicated to understand that big chunk of text :-) could you please rephrase it a bit?

Comment: where is your up and down arrow keys? Please paste it here so it is easier for us to code

Comment: @Zorkind i am  getting li tag with value and id inside that so how to select li tag one by one using arrow down ey or arrow up key and same time selected li value and id should get and place into hidden text box

Comment: Oh, i think i understand now, but you will need more code for that, and probably will want to use a library for keyboard biding. :-\

Comment: when you say "arrow key up" you mean the beyboard key. right?

Comment: in fact, that ajax code you wrote there, have nothing to do with what you want :-(

Comment: @Zorkind yes arrow key up/down means keyboard key will you please help me for this issue,  inside li  tag it contains values and id  how to get that one and value appear in text box all this by keypress only not mouse click

Comment: ajax code is retrieving values ,id from database and values and id in li tag

Comment: @bipen added keypress code upto here i know plz check how to go for further steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, if you add this code to your ajax call, it should do the trick.

From here on, you do what you need to do with the elements.

```
$(window).on('keydown', function(){
    switch(event.keyCode)
    {
        case 40:
            if($("li[active]").length == 0) 
                $("li:first()")
                .attr('active','1')
                .css('color','red');
            else
                $("li[active]")
                .removeAttr('active')
                .css('color','green')
                .next()
                .attr('active','1')
                .css('color','red');

            break;
        case 38:
            if($("li[active]").length == 0) 
                $("li:last()")
                .attr('active','1')
                .css('color','red');
            else
                $("li[active]")
                .removeAttr('active')
                .css('color','green')
                .prev()
                .attr('active','1')
                .css('color','red');

            break;
    }
    $("#hidden_id").get(0).value = $("li[active]").data('id');
});
```

Found out that there is a modern way to do this, so here you go.

```
$(window).on('keydown', function(e){
    switch(e.key)
    {
        case 'ArrowDown':
            if($("li[active]").length == 0) 
                $("li:first()")
                .attr('active','1')
                .css('color','red');
            else
                $("li[active]")
                .removeAttr('active')
                .css('color','green')
                .next()
                .attr('active','1')
                .css('color','red');

            break;
        case 'ArrowUp':
            if($("li[active]").length == 0) 
                $("li:last()")
                .attr('active','1')
                .css('color','red');
            else
                $("li[active]")
                .removeAttr('active')
                .css('color','green')
                .prev()
                .attr('active','1')
                .css('color','red');

            break;
    }
    $("#hidden_id").get(0).value = $("li[active]").data('id');
});
```

You can break down that chain of commands using variables, i didnt because i don't know what you will do with the elements, but it's fairly easy to adapt from here.

I painted the LI text in red or green, cause i didn't know what you want to happen when selected.

Comment: Added the code to set the hidden field value with the selected LI id.

Comment: actually it is same like autocomplete in that also values in li format comes one by one and can be selected by mouse or keyboard arrow up or down key

Comment: in my code autocompete not working so i am going this way.

Comment: Well you said you wanted it from keyboard. the autocomplete is something else entirely, it's a different problem, you are not being too specific with information, so i can't help you correctly.

Comment: this is like autocomplete but i am using my own created autocomplete getting results perfectly and even using mouse click getting the selected value but i want same thing with keyboard down key and up key.

Comment: just help me about how to select li value one by one using arrow down or up key